# Question about mirror modifier

Tags: mirror-modifier

I was doing this model with a tutorial. However, when I used the mirror modifier along the x-axis, no object appeared, and for the y-axis, the object stuck to the original object. Is it normal?

x-axis:
[image]

y-axis:
[image]

I wanted them to appear in this position, how can I make it?
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the moment the X axis makes the mirrored object overlap the original one, and the origin of the object is not correctly placed. You need to:

- Apply the rotation of your object if you want its local axis to be aligned with the global axis (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>A</kbd>)
- Put the origin of the object where you want the center of the *Mirror* to be. For example you can use the *Transform Affect Only Origins* option to move the origin (don't forget to disable the option once you've moved the origin):

[image]

Comment: It works, thanks.
https://imgur.com/a/KEmYPxg

Comment: Great then.........    ;)